# MOSFET N-channel

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I want to know what happend if you connect a N-channel MOSFET on the positive side of a load instead on the negative side of a load.How will it affect the Rds and what other problems would appear ?

[image]

Comment: It would work perfectly well in the circuit I'm seeing in my mind's eye but, that's my mind's eye and not yours so, assuming I'm not going to take up telepathy and that you want an answer, then maybe you need to put a few more words down or (preferably) make a diagram.

Comment: To turn it on you'd have to move Vgate above the Vsupply, which often needs a charge pump or a separate supply.

Comment: I uploaded a photo which describes better my words.

Comment: It's called a "source follower" (useful search term). What it does depends on its threshold Vgs and the drive signal (actual Vgs)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general (there are exceptions for fast changing signals where the lumped element model breaks down) components only care about the relative voltages between their terminals. Given the same gate source voltage and the same load you should see the same drain source voltage in both cases.

The problem is that generating that gate source voltage just got much trickier. With a N channel mosfet at the low end of the load the source voltage is tied to ground and so it's easy to put in place a positive voltage relative to it. With the N channel mosfet at the high end you need to generate a positive voltage relative to a source pin that is potentially at very nearly the voltage of your positive supply.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are querying if there is any appreciable difference in the MOSFET's characteristics when comparing sinking current or sourcing current to a load:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRprm8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As long as you drive the gate of the MOSFET with an equal Vgs (risetime and source capability if PWM'ing) then no, there is no difference.
The complication with using Ntypes with the load in the source & the PSU on the drain is the generation of a suitable gate voltage.